# How to read a text file and save all the file content into a two-dimensional character array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I really do help from you guys. I'm pretty new in C# and I'll honestly say that right now I'm doing my best to learn. Anyway, enough of the story. I have a text file that I will like to read with `StreamReader` and after which save all the content of the file into an array of char and the close the file.

Which, I successfully read the file content but the challenge now is saving the contents into an array of char and then use two-dimensional to display its content. Here is what I have so far!

The function that takes care of the file reading

```
private void ReadConfigFile()
{
        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;                             // To read the config file
            count = 0;                                          //config file counter variable

            inputFile = File.OpenText(@"config.txt");           //open the config file
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                configFile = inputFile.ReadLine();              //reads the config file
                count++;
            }
            inputFile.Close();
            numOfLines = count;
            //MessageBox.Show($"{numOfLines.ToString()}"); //For debugging
            JaggedArray(configFile, numOfLines);
            //Display();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Configuration File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

And, the function that actually displays the two-dimensional char array

```
    private void JaggedArray(string config, int numberOfLines)
    {
        boardArray = new char[numberOfLines][];   //Character array of the configuration file

        for (int r = 0; r < boardArray.Length; r++) //looping through rows of gameboard
        {
            r = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < boardArray[r].Length; c++) //looping through columns of gameboard
            {
                MessageBox.Show(boardArray[r][c].ToString()); //For debugging
            }
        }
    }
```

What I intended to achieve is to be able to put the file into a two-dimensional char array and also know how to make use if it in the `JaggedArray` function in other to manipulate it. I'll really appreciate any help render to me. Please, I'm only pleading and nothing more.

Comment: Your question seems to have [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please explain what your original requirement is. Aside from that, I'm pointing out two mistakes in your code: 1) the variable `configFile` will contain *only* the last line of the file because you're overwriting. 2) This line: `r = 0;`In your outer loop will probably lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, Ahmed...the requirement is to read a text file that content lines of text like these ones                                                      0040030001303020 0300200410000012  (12 rows and 16 columns) and then save all the content that you read into an array of char and that is should be dynamic. After which, display the contents

Comment: Okay, check my answer below. Btw, what you need is an *array of array of char* **and not** a *two-dimensional char array*. What you created above, `boardArray` **is actually** an array of an array of char which is totally different from [multidimensional arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the file's context into a *jagged array*, suggest using *Linq*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

char[][] data = File
  .ReadLines(@"config.txt")
  .Select(line => line.ToCharArray())
  .ToArray();
```

To display the array in one go you can use `string.Join` and *Linq*

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
// .Take(numberOfLines) // if you want to take just numberOfLines top lines
  .Select(line => string.Join("; ", line))); // put "" if you want to concat the chars

Console.Write(result);
```

Loop based implementation:

```
foreach (var line in data) {
  Console.WriteLine();

  foreach (char c in line) {
    Console.Write(c);
    Console.Write(' ');
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the characters of each line into a char array, and then put these arrays of char in a "container" array (which in that case would be an *array of array of char* **and not** a *two-dimensional array*. Please note that multi-dimensional arrays is a different thing which you can learn more about in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

Back to your question, you can use something like the following function to return the file contents in the desired format (an array of an array of char):

```
//A function that will read a file and return an array of an array of char.
char[][] ReadFileLinesAsArraysOfChar(string filePath)
{
    //Create a list of array of char.
    var lines = new List<char[]>();

    string line;
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Convert each line into a char array and add to the list.
        lines.Add(line.ToCharArray());
    }
    //Convert the list to an array (of array of char) and return.
    return lines.ToArray();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
//Create the array from file.
var boardArray = ReadFileLinesAsArraysOfChar(@"config.txt");

//Display each line in a message box for demonstration.
foreach (char[] line in boardArray)
{
    //Using 'new string()' to convert the char array back to a string.
    MessageBox.Show(new string(line));
}
```

Hope that helps :)